# Alterar nome do Button via código WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf

> Estou querendo acessar um controle no WPF para acessar as propriedades
>   dele e modificar.
>
> No entanto, não consigo achar muita abordagem sobre Wpf atualmente.
>
> O que quero fazer por exemplo, é alterar o nome de um `button` para
>   qualquer nome.

XAML

```
<Button Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Margin="362,31,0,0" Height="20" Click="Button_Click" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
        <Button.RenderTransform>
            <TransformGroup>
                <ScaleTransform/>
                <SkewTransform/>
                <RotateTransform Angle="360.279"/>
                <TranslateTransform/>
            </TransformGroup>
</Button.RenderTransform>
```

No XAML.CS, não sei como acessar o Button.

Comment: Inclua o seu código

Comment: @LeandroAngelo ok.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Essa não é a forma mais indicada para fazer isso (o correto seria utilizando `Binding`, mas não é o foco da pergunta), mas aqui está:

Defina o nome do seu botão no arquivo `.xaml` da sua `Window` através do atributo `x:Name`

```
<Button x:Name="btnMyButton" Content="OK" Width="200" Height="30" ></Button>
```

Com isso, você pode acessá-lo através do arquivo `.xaml.cs` da sua `Window` chamando o botão pelo nome criado anteriormente `btnMyButton`:

```
public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    // Altera o conteúdo do botão
    btnMyButton.Content = "Clique aqui";

    // Altera o comprimento do botão
    btnMyButton.Width = 100;

    // Altera a altura do botão
    btnMyButton.Height = 30;

    // Define um evento ao clicar no botão
    btnMyButton.Click += BtnMyButton_Click;
}

private void BtnMyButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```